# ROS Answers SE migration: openni_tracker

Tags: openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody

1.-I have  installed sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-openni-tracker

2.-I have also installed NiTE v1.5.2.21 Linux-x86, then I have  extracted the file to my Downloads directory, and I did the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads/NITE-Bin-Dev-Linux-x64-v1.5.2.21

sudo ./install.sh
```

Then cd /Samples/Bin/x86-Release$ ./Sample-Players
and works fine.

3.-Then I run rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker

4.- I stand in front of the Xtion pro and I get the following

New User 1
Calibration started for user 1
Calibration complete, start tracking user 1

But I cannot see any image, nothing

Any ideas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64047/openni_tracker/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per [OpenNI tracker package description](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_tracker): The tracker publishes the acquired poses of different joints like `head`, `neck`, ... to the tf tree.

From here, they can be accessed in different manners:

- For visualization, you can view them e.g. in RViz as you pointed out in your answer.
- If you want to access the transformations from code, have a look at the [tf    Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials).

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1